# How to render an existing template as a popup form on a separate page on the click of button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am making a web app using Django, I have a template which contains a form which needs to be filled by the user, now I want to provide an option so that the user can fill this form from a separate template by means of a button on this template, clicking on this button displays the original form as a popup form. I am able to open the original form on button click on a separate window but not as a popup on the same page.

I know that it will use JQuery and AJAX but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about, why not have the form be it's own HTML page and launch that page?  If you're talking about opening a link into a new browser page than you will want to add target="blank" to the anchor link.

Comment: I want that I can access the existing form from another page as well, it makes the data entry process smoother. I provide a button on this new page, clicking on which renders the desired form as a popup form.

Comment: well adding target="blank" to launch a new page will open it as a popup, which may be blocked by some browsers.

Comment: I want that I can access the form on a normal template of its own ( which I have right now) and provide a means of accessing this form from some other template as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate your template with form into two:

```
form.html
{# usual header and containers to work on separate page correctly #}
...
{% includes "your_app/includes/ajax_form.html" %}
....

ajax_form.html
{# just your form here or container that will be sent via ajax only #}
<form ...>
</form>
```

Also inside your template where you want to have popup you should again include your `ajax_form.html` template. Don't forget to set correct `action` in form to send requests to your `FormView`.

Then you have to create your view with overriden `get_template_names` method:

```
class YourFormView(FormView):
    ...
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return ['your_app/includes/ajax_form.html']
        return ['your_app/form.html']
```

Usual request - complete template is returned. Ajax request - only form template is returned.